# Facebook Pixel Helper doesn't load

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

I've installed the Facebook Pixel by following the Facebook tutorial, just before the `</head>` tag in my Joomla website. My pixel doesn't have any action included, just the default PageView inside the script block code. 
The test traffic show that my Facebook Pixel is enabled, although the Facebook Pixel Helper plugin is giving me the following error:

> "The Facebook pixel code on this page didn't load, so no information was sent to Facebook."

Any clue how to solve this problem?

Comment: Start by checking whether any other extensions in your browser might be blocking it for privacy reasons.

Comment: Hello, perfect, it was my adBlock extension, by disabling this extension the plugin seems to load the Facebook Pixel. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I had the same problem, caused by AdBlock. Maybe we should promote @CBroe comment as the answer?